# "topology was destroyed" error for update function in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm running into a `{ [MongoError: topology was destroyed] name: 'MongoError', message: 'topology was destroyed' }` error when trying to run an update command. My understanding of this error is that it is caused by the database connection being dropped, but that doesn't make sense given that it is just an update call to a model, correct? Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
/*Connect to the Database*/
var options = {
  server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 60000 } },
  replset: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 60000 } }
};
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    ObjectID = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

mongoose.connect('remote.database', options, function(err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);
});

// Schema for single user
var user_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    //Username, password information
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    name: String,
    session_ids: [String],
    session_id_times: [Number],

    //Khan Academy token, secret for accessing tree of knowledge
    khan_token: String,
    khan_secret: String,

    //Callback is for authenticating with khan
    khan_callback_id: String,

    //Proficiencies (data from khan API)
    proficiencies: [String],
    additional_skills: [String],

    //general recommended skills to learn next
    gen_skill_recs: [String]
});

var User = mongoose.model("user_schema", user_schema);

/*
    Logins a user without a password after they have authenticated with
    Khan. Is only called as a callback to AM.updateAuthentication which
    sets khan-callback_id to an empty string so that this only works after
    logging on and authenticating with Khan.
*/
exports.loginAfterAuthentication = function(user, callback){
    User.findOne({username: user}, function(err, o){
        if(err){
            callback('server-error');
        }else if(o){
            var ids = [];
            o.session_id_times.forEach(function(el, i) {
                if(d.getTime()-el > 24*60*60*14)
                    ids.push(i);
            });
            o.session_id_times = o.session_id_times.filter(function(el, i) {return ids.indexOf(i) == -1});
            o.session_ids = o.session_ids.filter(function(el, i) {return ids.indexOf(i) == -1});
            var session_id = generateSalt();
            var session_id_time = d.getTime();
            o.session_ids.push(session_id);
            o.session_id_times.push(session_id_time);
            User.findOneAndUpdate({username: user}, {session_ids: o.session_ids, session_id_times: o.session_id_times}, function(err, o){
                if(err)
                    callback('user-not-found');
                else{
                    callback(null, {'username': user, 'session_id': session_id});
                    //somewhat time consuming call
                    API.getUserExercises(o.khan_token, o.khan_secret).then(
                        function(result){
                            var addSkills = result;
                            // call to update proficiencies. Somewhat time consuming
                            API.getUserInfo(o.khan_token, o.khan_secret).then(
                                function(result){
                                    var profEx = result.proficient_exercises;
                                    function isntProficient(el){
                                        return profEx.indexOf(el) == -1;
                                    }
                                    // Updates proficiencies and removes additional_skills that have been added to
                                    // proficiencies
                                    console.log(user);
                                    console.log(profEx);
                                    console.log(addSkills.filter(isntProficient));
                                    User.update({username: user},{proficiencies: profEx,
                                        additional_skills: addSkills.filter(isntProficient)}, function(err) {
                                            if(err) callback(err); //This is where this error is triggered
                                            else updateClonesStatuses(user, function(){});
                                        });
                                }, function(error){
                                    callback('must-reauthenticate', o);
                                });
                        }, function(error) {
                            // if API.getUserInfo() throws an error the user's token
                            // and secret are depreciated and they must reauthenticate
                            // with Khan. Should happen very rarely
                            callback('must-reauthenticate', o);
                        });
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            callback('user-not-found');
        }
    });
}
```

`user` is the name of the user and both `profEx` and `addSkills.filter(isntProficient)` are reasonable values. Am I misunderstanding how connecting to mongo works in some way?

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose "topology destroy" error occurs when your node server has lost the TCP connection with mongodb server and its max retry connection limit has been crossed. In this case node js connection with mongodb becomes ideal and can't perform any operation on DB and when any request try to connect with mongodb(without node server restart) then it will throw the same error.